# Parallels Virtuozzo under Windows

Tags: virtuozzo

Here the logic chain:

1. Virtuozzo is a commercial version of OpenVZ
2. OpenVZ works by modifying the core of hosting OS, so it doesn't
   support Windows
3. Virtuozzo supports Windows

I do not understand how we can come to the fact that Virtuozzo supports Windows (but it really does). Have they modified Windows core some way? Or may be there are some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes they've modified Windows.

Longer answer: How they've done that is a business secret, however I know from running older versions of Virtuozzo on Windows that everything they do is accredited by Microsoft so that you can receive full support on a Virtuozzo Container through Parallels and subsequently Microsoft.

Comment: Based on the information from ITHedgeHog, it sounds like it may be through the ZEN technologies that Microsoft added to the more recent versions of Windows. That's the "enlightenment" stuff with the "paravirtualized" functionality/capabilities.